# Psexec batch file foor loop error

Tags: psexec

I have problem. All working on local machine but when use psexec i get error.
This is scrap of my .bat file

psexec.exe \%pc% cmd.exe /k for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%g in ('certutil -verifystore My ^| findstr /i "serial"') do echo %%g

On local cmd all its work but on remote i get error:
"At this point | was unexpected"

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Correct part of code 
(...) in ('"certutil -verifystore My | findstr /i serial"') do (...)